# Remove value from option select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have any chance to remove exp. value="1" option select?

Exp. that is my option select:

```
<select name="animals">
 <option value="0">dog</option>
 <option value="1">cat</option>
</select>
```

How to remove value="0" and value="1"?

I try this, that is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="/user/register/" onsubmit="test(this)">
<select name="animals" id="animals">
 <option value="0">dog</option>
 <option value="1">cat</option>
</select>
</form>
```

That is my test function:

```
function test(form) {
    form["#animals"].removeAttr("value");
}
```

But have error message:

```
form['#animals'] is undefined
```

Comment: I would "vote" to give the OP time to write what his problems are before closing the question

Comment: The OP should have written what his problems are before submitting the question. It's unclear if he wants to remove the value attribute or the option element. And SO is not a "input requirements, get code" service, we're here to help, not do all the work for people.

Comment: @MrOBrian 100% agree but he's a new user I would cut him a little bit of slack to come back and edit his question

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('option').removeAttr("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove an option :

```
$("select option[value='0'], select option[value='1']").remove();
```

Comment: i think he just wants to remove the attribute

Comment: well I *think* you can infer it from "How to remove value="0" and value="1"?". But yeah, not very clear

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('select[name="animals"] option[value="1"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems exist with your function

1. **form["#animals"]** is not the correct way to retrieve a element from a form.
   Use `form["animals"]` - use the name directly with no css selector
2. **form["animals"]** is not a jQuery object so the removeAttr will fail.
   Use `$(form["animals"])`

Instead just use `$(form["animals"]).find('option').removeAttr('value')`

Update:

```
//this will remove the attributes at load time
$(function() {
  $('#animals option').find('option').removeAttr('value');
});
```

Comment: Ok I try this, I click submit and page refresh, I see the html output code and attribut value is exist again?

Comment: well of course after a page refresh the elements exist, the changes are only client side.

Comment: Them have chance to remove value attr?

Comment: Well it seems that either you fix the code that creates the html that is returned for that page or use a script to remove those attributes at page load

Comment: I add you function <script>function</script> in page before my form but in html output code value is exist